# React hook query not updating on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component with two select inputs; Select A lets you select a size and then, based on what is selected, that size is passed into a React hook (getPackageBySize) that does a GET query that returns the option list of that size for Select B. So:

```
Select A = 100 should return options ['A','B','C']
Select A = 50 should return options ['X','Y','Z']
```

When the component loads with an initial size value of '100' it loads the correct options for Select B (['A','B','C']). However, if I then pick a new size from Select A, it does not update the options in Select B to ['X','Y','Z']. Here is the hook:

```
  const [
    options,
    refetchOptions,
  ] = getPackageBySize(
    props.size
  );
```

And a useEffect hook that calls the first hook again any time the size changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    refetchOptions(
      props.size
    );
  }, [props.size]);
```

And 'getPackageBySize' is:

```
export default (size: string) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [fetch, reFetch] = useAxios({
    options: {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        Authorization: getAuthToken(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      url:
        `${routes.search.api.ROOT}` +
        '?q=TYPE:"package" AND =size:"' +
        size +
        '"',
    },
    forceDispatch: () => true,

    handler: (error: any, response: any) => {
      if (error) {
        dispatch(
          addToast({
            labels: {
              heading: 'Error',
              details: `${error.message}`,
            },
            variant: 'error',
          })
        );
      }
      if (response) {
        return console.log('Response: ', response);
      }
    },
  });
  return [fetch, reFetch];
};
```

So on initial load it looks up the default size 100 and returns ['A', 'B', 'C']. When I change Select A to 50 I can see that getPackageBySize gets the correct size arg of '50'. It plugs it into the URL and the query is processed however when I get the response, I can see that the URL in the response is still using the original size:

```
url: "http://localhost:4001/http://site.local:8080/search/content?q=TYPE:"package" AND =size:"100""
```

If I leave the page and then return, it runs the query with the correct value of 50 and I get ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] back.

Does anyone know how to ensure the URL updates without having to leave the page and return?

Comment: When do you trigger an effect to rerun `getPackageBySize` to fetch anything again after the component mounts?

Comment: @DrewReese I have a useEffect hook that calls the first one with the size changes sorry about that, I added that to the original question.

Comment: Looks like refetchOptions is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) is there no warning that it's missing from the effect dependencies?

Comment: @HMR I didn't notice any warning but that sounds like my issue, thanks for the tip I'll have a look at that link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are not using a state to store the results returned by your axios call. If i'm right then it's normal. You need to update a state or a prop to trigger a re-rendering of your component (And so update your select value).